# How do I fetch just one object from the mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to get and res.send user_image from the table. I tried to use attributes: ['user_image'], but it does not work. Is there any other keyword or style to fetch just one object?

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('../models');

router.get('/image/:user_id', (req, res) => {
    try {
        db.Customer.findAll({
            where: {
                user_id: req.params.user_id,
                attributes: ['user_image'],
            },
        }).then((user) => res.send(user));
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Do you mean just one Column or just one Row

Comment: The user_image column

Comment: `res.send(user.user_image)`?

Comment: What is `db.Customer`? Is that Mongoose?

Comment: Not working. This is mySQL.